# trying to get create a simple bar chart from charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with this simple bar charts_flutter code. Although I have no errors in my code, only the x-axis gets displayed onto the screen.

I suspect it's because of the SingleChildScrollView messing with the grey container's margins, but I'm not so sure since the x-axis was able to display. Any ideas and help would be much appreciated.

Sidenote: Are there any good tutorials for charts_flutter?

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like

[image]

Here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Bar chart example
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class BarChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series<dynamic, String>> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  BarChartWidget(this.seriesList, {this.animate = false});

  /// Creates a [BarChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory BarChartWidget.withSampleData() {
    return BarChartWidget(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      child: charts.BarChart(
        seriesList,
        animate: animate,
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
      OrdinalSales('2015', 25),
      OrdinalSales('2016', 100),
      OrdinalSales('2017', 75),
    ];

    return [
      charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Grey Container where the graph should be

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bar_chart_sample1.dart';

class BarChartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BarChartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 166, 166, 166),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            BarChartWidget([]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Overall Page containing the Grey Container

```
body: TabBarView(
  children: [
    Column(
      
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Obx(
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
            height: 20,
            child: DefaultTabController(
              initialIndex: 0,
              length: 3,
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: TabBar(
                    indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: "About",
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: "Stats",
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: "Activity",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
--->         child: LineChartPage(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.personDigging),
          Text("Coming soon!"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```